# Terminology Emotion-Generic Error When Viewing Images

Tags: terminology, emotion

This has been bugging me for a little, I have no experience with the emotion libraries.

I installed terminology with

```
sudo apt-get install terminology
```

Unfortunately when I try to set a background for the terminal or use tycat I get the following error:

```
emotion-generic modules/emotion/generic/emotion_generic.c:1838 _players_load() no generic players available
```

I've did this:

```
sudo apt-get install libemotion-dev
```

and this:

```
sudo apt-get install totem
```

It hasn't helped and I do get the same error.

I would love to use terminology for all it's great features instead of using the boring terminal I have now. I use terminal for just about everything I do.

The project is [located here](https://www.enlightenment.org/about-terminology)

[image: Terminology tycat]

Comment: what base language is this for? O.o

Comment: Not too sure Oliver but I updated the question with more information.

Comment: From the error, you should try to install a "generic player". Do you have totem, or something installed already? If yes, then the question becomes "how to define it as generic?".

Comment: I have totem installed and it is the latest version :/

Comment: above error is due to installation issues and by removing existing, restarting and then reinstalling, then it will work

Comment: I compiled it from source then it worked just fine it was an issue with the repository installation at the time.